# onDraw(Canvas canvas) never reached?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

Can anyone help, my app does not seem to do the onDraw() in the GraView class, even if .invalidate is called upon from either inside or outside the class. I managed to figure out with system.err that it does invalidate the view, however it never gets in the onDraw( ), even though the rest of the app keeps running. I found a lot of solutionssuggesting putting setWillNotDraw(false) in the constructor, but that did not solve anything.

GravIO.java File:

```
package dabawi.gravitas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class GravIO extends Activity implements Runnable, OnTouchListener   {
public final static int clock = 1000;
private GravEngine engine;
private GraView TV;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private Thread t1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    t1 = new Thread(this);
    t1.start();
    engine = new GravEngine();
    TV = new GraView(this, engine);
    setContentView(TV);
    TV.setOnTouchListener(this);
    TV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
    //mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    System.err.println("Starting Engine") ;

    run();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.err.println("Tik") ;
            engine.tick();
            TV.invalidate();
            Thread.sleep(GravIO.clock);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("faal");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    engine.switchGravity();
    return true;
}

}
```

GraView.java File:

```
package dabawi.gravitas;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

@SuppressLint({ "DrawAllocation", "ViewConstructor" })
public class GraView extends View {
private GravEngine engine;
private int screenWidth, screenHeight, ySpace = 5, xSpace, scale;
private Paint paint;
private int xLoc, yLoc;
private boolean xWall = false, yWall = false;

public GraView(Context context, GravEngine engine) {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    this.engine = engine;
    calcScale(context);
}

@Override // We think the problem is with this method, that it is never called upon.
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    System.err.println("Calculating position");
    calcPos();
    canvas = new Canvas();
    // drawing background
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    drawGame(canvas);
}

private void drawGame(Canvas canvas) {
    drawRoom(canvas);
    drawPlayer(canvas);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void calcScale(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    screenWidth = d.getWidth();
    screenHeight = d.getHeight();
    scale = screenHeight / ySpace;
    xSpace = screenWidth / scale;
}

private void calcPos() {
    xLoc = (engine.getxPlayer() / GravEngine.roomScaling);
    yLoc = (engine.getyPlayer() / GravEngine.roomScaling);
    if (xLoc < (xSpace + 1) / 2) {
        xLoc = (xSpace + 1) / 2;
        xWall = true;
    } else if (xLoc > (GravRoom.xSize - ((xSpace + 1) / 2))) {
        xLoc = GravRoom.xSize - ((xSpace + 1) / 2);
        xWall = true;
    } else {
        xWall = false;
    }
    if (yLoc < (ySpace + 1) / 2) {
        yLoc = (ySpace + 1) / 2;
        yWall = true;
    } else if (yLoc > (GravRoom.xSize - ((ySpace + 1) / 2))) {
        xLoc = GravRoom.ySize - ((ySpace + 1) / 2);
        yWall = true;
    } else {
        yWall = false;
    }
}

private void drawPlayer(Canvas canvas) {
    float xPos = engine.getxPlayer() / GravEngine.roomScaling, yPos = engine
            .getyPlayer() / GravEngine.roomScaling;
    if (xWall) {

    }
    if (yWall) {

    }
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    int left = (int) (xPos * scale), top = (int) (yPos * scale);
    int right = left + (GravEngine.pxSize / GravEngine.roomScaling) * scale;
    int bot = top + (GravEngine.pySize / GravEngine.roomScaling) * scale;
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bot, paint);
}

private void drawRoom(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0, x = xLoc - ((xSpace + 1) / 2); i < xSpace + 1; x++, i++) {
        for (int j = 0, y = yLoc - ((ySpace + 1) / 2); i < ySpace + 1; y++, j++) {
            drawRoomPart(x,y,i,j,canvas);
        }
    }
}

private void drawRoomPart(int x, int y, int i, int j, Canvas canvas) {
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < GravRoom.xSize && y < GravRoom.ySize) {
        short type = engine.getRoom(engine.getCurrentRoom()).getGridPos(x,y);
        if (type != 0) {
            drawBlock(canvas, i, x, j, y, type);
        }
    }
}

private void drawBlock(Canvas canvas, int i, int x, int j, int y, short type) {
    int left = i * scale, top = y * scale;
    int right = left + scale;
    int bot = top + scale;
    paint.setColor(colorBlock(type));
    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bot, paint);
    System.err.println("Left" + left + "   top:   " + top + "  right:  "
            + right + "   bot:   " + bot);
}

private int colorBlock(short type) {
    if (type == 1) {
        return Color.DKGRAY;
    } else if (type == 2) {
        return Color.CYAN;
    } else if (type == 3) {
        return Color.GREEN;
    } else if (type == 4) {
        return Color.RED;
    } else {
        return Color.MAGENTA;
    }
}

// private void imageBlock(short type) {
//
// }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ouch !

Your call to your run method is executed in the UIThread (as the onCreate method), and it's doing an infinite loop in it.
Just add a println after the call and you will see that the UI thread is never released, your application should not even start !

Comment: Thank you for the response, it does explain a lot. From what I understand of it, it should help if the run will be executed in another thread (correct me if I am wrong), but if so how to do this slit easily on android?

Comment: The faster way is to replace "run()" by "new Thread(this).start();"

Comment: But you should see this thing differently, First implement method onMesure of your view and  there retreive width and height, this will be more accurate than defaultDesplay. Then, get your thread in the view, in it calculate the position of your items and when it's done, call invalidate method. Thus, the computing won't be on the ui thread. Also do not create object like Paint on the draw method. Also, why are you creating a new canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any changes because you are creating a new canvas and drawing on that. To fix this, remove the line

```
canvas = new Canvas();
```

Also, you should initiate your `Paint` outside of the `onDraw` method (this is an optimization recommended by the Android documentation).